# Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: node.js, typescript, router

My application is in nodejs with typescript. Im trying to segregate the routing, and introducing interface and controller for executing the later logic.

**app.ts**

```
const countryRoutes = require('./routes/countryroute')
app.use('/countries', countryRoutes)
```

**countryRoute.ts**

```
var countryuController = require('./../controller/country/countrycontroller')
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

router.get('/getValidCountry', countryController.validCountry)
module.exports = router
```

**ICountryController.ts**

```
interface ICountryController {
    validCountry(req: any, res: any)
}
```

**CountryController.ts**

```
class CountryController {
    constructor() {}
    validCountry(req: any, res: any) {
        //application Logic here
    }
}

module.exports = CountryController
```

Things work fine till **countryRoute.ts** but after that the control dont go to **countryController.ts**, it gives the below error

```
Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
```

I tried changing the way of writing the method in controller file but i get the same exception. Also i have tried solutions for other questions but none worked for me.

Any suggestion on how i can write the function in the class file for **.get** function to accept.

Comment: Did this happen due to the typo in `countryuController` (extra U) ? Would like to hear how you got it to work in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try for the following:

Change **countryRoute.ts** as follows:

```
var countryuController = require('./../controller/country/countrycontroller')
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

router.get('/getValidCountry', function(req, res){
   countryController.validCountry(req, res))
});
module.exports = router
```

Comment: actually dont want to implement that approve, i want to call the controller function as the second argument itself as there are alot of routing

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your application struct like so :

just make a file with name **routes.ts** and then define functions in it

```
var countryuController = require('./../controller/country/countrycontroller');

module.export = (app) => {
  app.get("/getValidCountry" , countryController.validCountry);
}
```

and use routes in your **app.ts** like this :

```
const app = express();
const routes = require("./routes");

routes(app);
```

with this way you can chain multiple controllers too :D !